# OpenCPU and jsonlite: column-based "/json" versus row-based

Tags: json, r, opencpu, jsonlite

Is there a clean way to change the default "/json" postfix option on data.frames to be column-based versus row-based?

Data.frames in R, if I understand correctly, are really just named lists where each list is the same length as the others. Using `jsonlite`, it's simple to show the difference (trivial example, yes):

```
library(jsonlite)
ll <- list(xx=1:3, yy=6:8)
dd <- data.frame(xx=1:3, yy=6:8)
toJSON(dd)
# [1] "[ { \"xx\" : 1, \"yy\" : 6 }, { \"xx\" : 2, \"yy\" : 7 }, { \"xx\" : 3, \"yy\" : 8 } ]"
toJSON(ll)
# [1] "{ \"xx\" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], \"yy\" : [ 6, 7, 8 ] }"
toJSON(dd, dataframe='column')
# [1] "{ \"xx\" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], \"yy\" : [ 6, 7, 8 ] }"
toJSON(as.list(dd))
# [1] "{ \"xx\" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], \"yy\" : [ 6, 7, 8 ] }"
```

where the last three are identical. It's easy to force it to look the same either by using the `dataframe` argument to `toJSON` or by coercing the `data.frame` into a `list`.

Using OpenCPU's API, the calls look similar:

```
$ curl http://localhost:7177/ocpu/library/base/R/list/json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "xx":[1,2,3], "yy":[6,7,8] }'
{
        "xx" : [
                1,
                2,
                3
        ],
        "yy" : [
                6,
                7,
                8
        ]
}

$ curl http://localhost:7177/ocpu/library/base/R/data.frame/json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "xx":[1,2,3], "yy":[6,7,8] }'
[
        {
                "xx" : 1,
                "yy" : 6
        },
        {
                "xx" : 2,
                "yy" : 7
        },
        {
                "xx" : 3,
                "yy" : 8
        }
]
```

If I want the `data.frame` itself to be JSON-ified column-based then I need to coerce it to a `list`:

```
$ curl http://localhost:7177/ocpu/library/base/R/data.frame -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "xx":[1,2,3], "yy":[6,7,8] }'
/ocpu/tmp/x000a0fb8/R/.val
/ocpu/tmp/x000a0fb8/stdout
/ocpu/tmp/x000a0fb8/source
/ocpu/tmp/x000a0fb8/console
/ocpu/tmp/x000a0fb8/info

$ curl http://localhost:7177/ocpu/library/base/R/as.list/json -d "x=x000a0fb8"
{
        "xx" : [
                1,
                2,
                3
        ],
        "yy" : [
                6,
                7,
                8
        ]
}
```

Three questions:

1. Is there a way to change the default behavior of the OpenCPU auto-JSON-ification to be column-based?
2. Is there a reason (besides "had to default to something") that it defaults to row-based? (So that I can better understand the underpinnings and efficiencies, not meant as a challenge.)
3. This is all academic, though, since most (if not all) libraries accepting the JSON output will understand and translate between the formats transparently. Right?

(Win7 x64, R 3.0.3, opencpu 1.2.3, jsonlite 0.9.4)

(PS: Thanks, Jeroen, OpenCPU is awesome! The more I play, the more I like.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `dataframe` objects you can use `HTTP GET` and set the `dataframe` argument:

```
GET http://localhost:7177/ocpu/tmp/x000a0fb8/json?dataframe=rows
```

For example the `Boston` object from the `MASS` package is a dataframe as well:

```
https://cran.ocpu.io/MASS/data/Boston/json?dataframe=columns
https://cran.ocpu.io/MASS/data/Boston/json?dataframe=rows
```

For `HTTP GET` requests to a `.../json` endpoint, all the http parameters are mapped to arguments in the `toJSON` function from the [jsonlite package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=jsonlite). You can can also specify other `toJSON` arguments:

```
https://cran.ocpu.io/MASS/data/Boston/json?dataframe=columns&digits=4
```

To see which arguments are available, have a look at the [jsonlite manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/jsonlite.pdf) or [this post](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/publishing-data-with-opencpu/).

Note that this only works if you do the 2 step procedure: first a `HTTP POST` on a function that returns a `dataframe`, followed by retrieving that object in `json` format with a `HTTP GET` request. You can not specify `toJSON` parameters when you do the 1-step shortcut where you fix the `POST` request with `/json`, because in `POST` requests the HTTP parameters always get mapped to the function call.

The reason for this default is that the row based design seems to be the most conventional and interoperable way of encoding tabular data. The [jsonlite paper/vignette](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2805) goes into some more detail. Note that it also works the other way around: you don't have to call the `data.frame` function to create a dataframe, just posting an argument in the form:

```
[{"xx":1,"yy":6},{"xx":2,"yy":7},{"xx":3,"yy":8}]
```

will automatically turn it into a data frame:

```
curl https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R/summary/console -d object='[{"xx":1,"yy":6},{"xx":2,"yy":7},{"xx":3,"yy":8}]'
```

Comment: I had seen the "digits" option added in other examples but hastily assumed that it was an option for the original function, not to `toJSON`. That clarifies a lot. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, your work on sandboxing through RAppArmor is awesome; are there plans or efforts to include a standardized way to streamline addition of user authentication methods? (Both for access to methods and access to data, potentially.) I know it has little to do with the computational aspects of OpenCPU, but it could certainly help in many situations. (I personally prefer open source and availability of data and code, but my boss and my paycheck don't always agree with that philosophy.)

Comment: You mean in OpenCPU? The `opencpu` cloud server is just standard http on `apache2` and `nginx`, it shouldn't be too difficult to configure basic auth or LDAP or something.

Comment: I'm having to look at limiting the availability of functions and data **in R** on a per-user and/or per-group basis. I'm attempting to implement something in place to make it work now, but I'm always a fan of plagiarizing if it's legal and good code. Perhaps OAuth2 or something ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the GET request you can transform in Javascript:

```
var df = [
        {"id":1,"Sepal.Length":5.1,"Sepal.Width":3.5,"Petal.Length":1.4,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},
        {"id":2,"Sepal.Length":4.9,"Sepal.Width":3,"Petal.Length":1.4,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},
        {"id":3,"Sepal.Length":4.7,"Sepal.Width":3.2,"Petal.Length":1.3,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"}
        ]

var columns = Object.keys(df[0]);
var dfcolumns = {};
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var column = [];
    var colname = columns[i];
    for (j = 0; j < df.length; j++) {
        column.push(df[j][colname]);
    }
    dfcolumns[colname] = column;
}

console.log(dfcolumns);
```

Result:

```
{ id: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  'Sepal.Length': [ 5.1, 4.9, 4.7 ],
  'Sepal.Width': [ 3.5, 3, 3.2 ],
  'Petal.Length': [ 1.4, 1.4, 1.3 ],
  'Petal.Width': [ 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 ],
  Species: [ 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa' ] }
```